# Nuxtjs application structure for mixed type of pages

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

In my application a bunch of pages can be generated statically. There are some pages which could run in browser (no SEO required). Some pages need to be having huge set of dynamic data which I hope could better be SSR. What would be the approach to maintain this kind of project? Do I need to maintain static files in separate project and other categories in separate project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently managing with 2 separate projects. One handles dynamic data part using SPA. Another project uses static generation. SSR was not an option.